# Provide sunglasses when filtering Review by a favourite tag... or stop the highlighting

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-watching

When reviewing posts, we have the options to filter those shown by a tag.

However, when filtering by a favourite tag, ***allll*** the posts are highlighted, which makes the whole page very (*un-necessarily*) bright:

[image]

Can we have the same behaviour as that when viewing questions listed under a favourite tag? (i.e. only the questions which match *another* of your favourite tags are highlighted).

Comment: I'd call a white background brighter than a dingy yellow.  But I can see the pointlessness of it as well.